# Object initializer syntax (c#) in python?

Tags: c#, python, class, instantiation

I was wondering if there is a quick way to initialise an object in python.

For example in c# you can instantiate an object and set the fields/properties like...

```
SomeClass myObject = new SomeClass() { variableX = "value", variableY = 120 };
```

Thanks

Brian

Comment: It's even better with `var`: `var myObject = new ....`

Comment: Changed from `Object` to `SomeClass` because in its original form, that was a compiler error.

Comment: It was c#-like pseudo code but ok :)

Comment: For arbitrary Python objects (ones you don't control), there isn't a nice syntax. I think the answers below give good suggestions if you do control the object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a quick dirty object with some fields, I highly suggest using [namedtuples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

```
from collections import namedtuple
SomeClass = namedtuple('Name of class', ['variableX', 'variableY'], verbose=True)
myObject = SomeClass("value", 120)

print myObject.variableX
```

Comment: And if you want a "real class" that also has `namedtuple` behavior, you can inherit from a `namedtuple`

Answer (score 2):

If you control the class, you can implement your own by making each public field settable from the comstructor, with a default value Here's an example (in Python3) for an object with `foo` and `bar` fields:

```
class MyThing:
    def __init__(self, foo=None, bar=None):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
```

We can instantiate the class above with a series of named arguments corresponding to the class values.

```
thing = MyThing(foo="hello", bar="world")

# Prints "hello world!"
print("{thing.foo} {thing.bar}!")
```

**Update 2017** The easiest way to do this is to use the [`attrs` library](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/)

```
import attr

@attr.s
class MyThing:
    foo = attr.ib()
    bar = attr.ib()
```

Using this version of `MyThing` just works in the previous example.  `attrs` gives you a bunch of dunder methods for free, like a constructor with defaults for all public fields, and sensible `str` and comparison functions. It all happens at class definition time too; zero performance overhead when using the class.

Comment: nice solution. imho, nicer than the namedtuple-thing

Comment: Thanks! I think the `kwargs` are unnecessary since you can specify default arguments right in the functions interface.  Going to edit for that, and to mention `attrs` which can do this automatically.

Comment: If I understand properly this would be mutually exclusive with something like sql alchemy, right?

Comment: There's an [attrs-sqlalchemy](https://pypi.org/project/attrs-sqlalchemy/) integration that gives you equality and comparison operations, as well as a nicer representation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
>>> import collections
>>> Thing = collections.namedtuple('Thing', ['x', 'y'])
>>> t = Thing(1, 2)
>>> t
Thing(x=1, y=2)
>>> t.x
1
>>> t.y
2
```