# Object initialization in Pythonnet

Tags: c#, ironpython, python.net, object-initializers

Let's assume I've the following C# class:

```
public class Test
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;
}
```

I want to use the above C# `Test` class from [IronPython](https://ironpython.net/) and as well from [CPython](https://www.python.org/) (using [Pythonnet](https://pypi.org/project/pythonnet/)).

Using [IronPython 2.7](https://ironpython.net/) I was able to generate an object and initializes the fields using [object initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers), see the following Python code:

```
obj = Test(X = 1.0, Y = 2.0)
```

See as well the following question [Object initialization in IronPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42109930/object-initialization-in-ironpython)

Using [CPython 3.9.7](https://www.python.org/) and [Pythonnet 3.01](https://pypi.org/project/pythonnet/) the above code returns the following error:

```
TypeError: No method matches given arguments for Test..ctor: ()
```

As workaround I can use the following Python code:

```
obj = Test()
obj.X = 1.0
obj.Y = 2.0
```

But I would like to use [object initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers).

Comment: I've opened an issue on GitHub, see https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/2038

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I get your question, but try this:

```cs
Test test = New Test();
/* or */ var test = New Test();
/* then */ test.x = whatever;
```

Comment: The `New` keyword and the `;` are not needed in Python.

Comment: I want to use my C# class from IronPython and CPython (using PYTHONNET).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways in C#:

1. [Object Initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) approach:

   ```cs
   var obj = new Test { X = 1.0, Y = 2.0 };
   ```
2. The [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors) approach. For this approach you must add a constructor to the class:

   ```cs
   public class Test
   {
       public double X;
       public double Y;

       public Text( double x, double y)
       {
           X = x;
           Y = y;
       }
   }
   ```

   Then you can create the object with:

   ```cs
   var obj = new Test(1.0, 2.0);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in my case I don't have the source code of .NET assembly.

Comment: You can derive a class from a C# class in IronPython. This would allow you to add it a constructor (`__init__()`).

Comment: But what if the C# class is `sealed`?

Comment: Then write a factory method.